# Use proxy for entry Ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, proxy, linux-networking

I'm using Lantern as my VPN service.

When I connect to Lantern it configures itself as system proxy. The problem is the proxy sometimes doesn't get detected by some programs or scripts and I have to manually configure proxy settings for these programs.

Is there a way to configure it as VPN or is there a program that translates the VPN calls to proxy calls and forwards them to the proxy server? Or there is any other way to make proxy work for entry system like VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lantern is **not** a VPN, but a proxy service that works through an open-source peer-to-peer network. So it's not possible top use Lantern for network routing (as in "use this route for all packets"). You will have to configure all your applications to use the proxy, as proxying lives on the application layer (not network layer).